# Cron not running because of simplexml_load_string error

Tags: magento-1.9, simplexml

I have some trouble receiving order emails so i debuged a bit.

- Installed AOE Scheduler

Found some issues with the cron so i checked this. Now its running but keeps sending me the following errors:

When trying to run schedular_cron.sh:

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function simplexml_load_string() in /path/to/magento/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
```

When trying to run cron.sh (Mage default):

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function simplexml_load_file() in /path/to/magento/app/Mage.php on line 767
```

Both *.sh files are executable and have the right owner.

Based on my phpinfo() SimpleXML is enabled.
Also, `if (extension_loaded('simplexml'))` tells me its loaded.

Comment: What is your PHP version ?

Comment: My PHP version is 5.4.45

Comment: did you found solution ?

Answer (score 3):

This errors means you do not have the simpleXML library loaded with PHP.

You should print your `phpinfo()` in Command Line mode and check the presence of the simplexml library.

Check then how to install the simplexml library on your OS.

Comment: In my phpinfo it looks enabled: Simplexml support enabled
Revision  $Id: (number) $ Schema support enabled

Comment: Did you check the Apache or the CLI ?
Your cron run in CLI i guess.

Comment: Yes its running in CLI, what do you mean by this question?

Comment: just to be sure you've checked your config using the CLI, not in a browser. Apache and CLI can have different settings.

Comment: Ok, so am i checking it the right way or?

Comment: did you found solution ?

Answer (score 3):

The error output is common when php-xml extension is not installed (or unavailable) for the PHP CLI.

To fix it, install php-xml (for your version of PHP) using:

For PHP 5.4

```
sudo apt-get install php5-xml
```

For PHP 5.6

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml
```

Then restart php5-fpm

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

After installation of php-xml, if you encounters such as:

> Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with message 'pdo_mysql extension is not
>   installed' in /var/www/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php

Then, install pdo-mysql and php5-gd
For PHP 5.4

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd php5-mysql
```

For PHP 5.6

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd php5.6-mysql
```

Then restart php5-fpm

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 2):

On the command line, do:

```
$ php -m    # shows modules enabled for CLI
$ php --ini # shows configs being used
```

Run `phpinfo()` in the browser and decided what you need to change based on the settings for your webserver.

Comment: SimpleXML is enabled in CLI. What should i look for to change since the error is about SimpleXML ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes You must restart (if You have in Your PHP instalation) an FPM, in my situation: service php7.1-fpm restart
Without this restart, I have a "Call to undefined function simplexml_load_file" although php7.1-xml was correctly installed and enabled (... from phpinfo() )

Answer (score -1):

Try to include the module path:

```
php -c /etc/php.d/
```